# Filter file "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_Computername_Username_File.json" by Computername/Username

Tags: powershell

I have a folder containing text-files with a standardized naming-scheme like:

```
2021-03-16_21-25-55_Client1_Edward.Hall_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-25-33_Client2_Eloise.Glover_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-17-38_Client3_Millie.Walsh_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-17-30_Client4_Lilly.Morton_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-15-45_Client5_Tia.Curtis_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-15-23_Client1_Edward.Hall_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-15-10_Client1_Lilly.Morton_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-15-03_Client2_Eloise.Glover_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-12-14_Client2_Eloise.Glover_ServerResponse.json
2021-03-16_21-11-25_Client3_Administrator_ServerResponse.json
```

I want to filter the files and retrieve the latest file (LastWriteTime) of a specific Computername-/Username-combination. Therefore I want to use a code like this:

```
# $env:COMPUTERNAME = "Client1"
# $env:USERNAME     = "Edward.Hall"

$MyFolder = "C:\MyFolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $MyFolder -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { 

    $_.Extension -eq ".json" -and $_.COMPUTERNAME -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME -and $_.USERNAME -eq $env:USERNAME

} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1
```

Of course the part `-and $_.COMPUTERNAME -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME -and $_.USERNAME -eq $env:USERNAME` is NOT working and should only show up the direction to what I imagine.

In the example above the result should be the file "**2021-03-16_21-25-55_Client1_Edward.Hall_ServerResponse.json**".

I was thinking of using `-match`, but it should be a exact match `-eq`.
Could you please help me to find a solution for this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can count on the name format always conforming to that standard you can just split up the name strings for your required sections:

```
# $env:COMPUTERNAME = "Client1"
# $env:USERNAME     = "Edward.Hall"

$MyFolder = "C:\MyFolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $MyFolder -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { 

    ($_.Extension -eq ".json") -and ($_.Name.Split('_')[2] -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) -and ($_.Name.Split('_')[3] -match $env:USERNAME)

} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: Nice idea. I like it. I was thinking of much more complex regex or something like that. Is there a specific reason why you compare the Computername with `-eq` and the Username with `-match`? Thank you!

Comment: Using -eq it must be exact, thus removes the possiblity of mathcing both "CLient1" and "Client2". A typo on my part, both should really be -eq if you want to avoid false positives

Comment: Alright. I have marked it as answer. Thank you very much!